# Microsoft access cant find file on path

Tags: vba, ms-access, path

Hello I keep getting an error message saying the path is wrong. I'm new at VBA Code and I just don't know how to solve it. This is what I wrote. I keep checking the path every time and copy-pasting the path and yet it can't find it. Sorry for my English - not main language.

Error message is:

```
Run time errror
Could not find file A:\Proccess_Assig1.accdb'.
```

The code is

```
Private Sub btn_buscar_Click()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strsql As String

    strsql = "Select * from TBlClientes Where id= " & txtCliente.Value & ""
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=A:\Proccess_Asig1.accdb;persist security Info=False"
    conn.Open
    rs.Open strsql, conn
    If rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Id no existe"
        txtCliente.Value = Nothing
        txtNombre.Value = Nothing
        txtApellido.Value = Nothing
        txtTelefono.Value = Nothing
    Else
        txtCliente.Value = rs.Fields("Nombre")  
        txtApellido.Value = rs.Fields("ApellidoPaterno")
        txtTelefono.Value = rs.Fields("Teléfono")
    End If
    rs.Close
    conn.Close

    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you insert your 3.5" in diskette into your PC's A: drive?

Comment: `A:\` is a floppy disk. Do you really have a disk in that drive that has an Access database on it? I find it pretty unlikely.

Comment: You copy/paste that path from Windows Explorer? You really have a computer with a 3.5-inch floppy disk drive?

Comment: query might be malformed as well.  in access strings are deliminted by ' '.  txtCliente could be a string?  if so wrap txtCliente's value in ' '  like: Where id= '" & txtCliente.Value & "'"

Comment: @mazoula, I would expect **ID** field to be number type so text delimiters are not relevant. Using **txt** as prefix for textbox name may be misleading. I use **tbx**, **cbx**, **lbx** as prefixes.

Comment: Locate the folder you need in Windows 10 File Explorer.  Right Click on the explorers address bar and select copy location as text.  Plug that in with the file name.  Your code shows the A:\ root directory.  Is your file in the root directory? It should look something like 'A:\yourfilefolder\Proccess_Asig1.accdb' - also, try using single hash marks on either end of the file reference like I did here.  ie Source='A:\Proccess_Asig1.accdb'

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the actual valid path A:\Proccess_Assig1.accdb doesn't seem like a standard path, try c:\Proccess_Assig1.accdb